# SQL - Get average salary for each dpartment and number of courses taught in that department

Tags: mysql, sql

A seemingly basic query that is giving me lots of problems. I had completed one similar but can't seem to get this right. I have three tables I'm looking up from:

**CM** - Describes departments in the company with fields 
         **DEPT**, BUDGET

**EM** - describes employees with fields **ID**, NAME, DEPT, SALARY

**CR** - describes courses taught with fields **Cnum**, Department, ID

Fields in bold are primary keys.

I Thought this would work immediately, but it only returned one department with an average for the enitre salary column:

```
 select CM.Dept, CM.Budget, avg(EM.Salary), count(distinct(CR.Cnum)) 
 from CM join EM join CR 
 where CM.DEPT = EM.DEPT and CM.DEPT = CR.DEPT 
 group by CM.DEPT;
```

Comment: Hint, `group by`... Also use `join` over commas in the `from` clause...

Comment: Ok, awesome! Its showing more departments and everything else appropriately but now its only returning 3 of the 4 departments. I noticed that the CR table that lists the courses is missing the 4th department. I'm guessing I would have to do a subquery for this instead of including the CM.Dept = CR.Dept ?

Comment: You can't use `join EM join CR` without specifying the columns they should join on. It's surprising you didn't get a syntax error with what you posted; either you didn't actually use it or MySQL is seriously broken. The proper syntax is `join EM on EM.column = CM.column`, where *column` should be replaced with the appropriate column names.

Comment: It was used and I did not recieve any errors. That's how I was able to respond.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @sgeddes hints your description implies a summary of your data by some fixed columns (CM.Dept, CM.Budget). This in SQL words implies to use group by. Group by requires to specify what columns you are grouping by and any others not in the grouping require an aggregation function, more info http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp. Perhaps something like shown below. That website also talks about the use of join.

```
select CM.Dept, CM.Budget, avg(EM.Salary), count(distinct(CR.Cnum)) 
from CM, EM, CR 
where CM.DEPT = EM.DEPT and CM.DEPT = CR.DEPT
group by CM.Dept, CM.Budget
```

**EDIT:**
After you understand the concept of “group by” and have some working code, it would be
best practice to replace the FROM with commas with the JOIN syntax. It would look something like below. JOIN is also explained in the link above.

```
select CM.Dept, CM.Budget, avg(EM.Salary), count(distinct(CR.Cnum)) 
from CM
INNER JOIN EM 
ON CM.DEPT = EM.DEPT
INNER JOIN CR 
ON CM.DEPT = CR.DEPT
group by CM.Dept, CM.Budget
```

Comment: It's a shame you decided to answer using an antiquated syntax that was superceded two decades ago by the JOIN syntax. There should never be a comma in your FROM clause; if there is, you're doing something very wrong (which is something else also mentioned by @sgeddes in the comment you cite).

Comment: Ken, I agree the join syntax is more modern and widely used, and will add that to my post .